# Is there a way to respond to a password request in a .command script

Tags: bash, macos

This is the script I'm trying to execute:

```
sudo reboot
Password:
```

How do I type my password in response to this question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "YourPassword" | sudo -S reboot
```

You can simply pipe your password to de password-prompt.

> -S, --stdin Write the prompt to the standard error and read the password from the standard input instead of using the terminal device. The password must be followed by a newline character.

Comment: Instead you give permission to `sudo reboot` without password to the user running the script. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13058/310674